# automate asserting network payload data

Tags: automation, cypress

does cypress support validating the data under Network / Payload tab ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes there are ways to do this.

Look around in the offical site under the network requests:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests

Comment: Nice what about good example that I can follow .Sorry I’m new to cypress